# Not able to Mock the db proper;y..gives NULL POINTER EXCEPTION each time i go to mock

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit5

> //this is the dao class I am provding ...trying write junit test cases for controllere class for    public Response postForm(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody User user)
> this method  and every time i get null pointer exception

<kbd>getting null pointer exception in test class<kbd>your text</kbd></kbd>

```
@Component
public class UserLoginDao extends CommonDao {

    @Autowired
    private MailMessages mailMessages;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserMessages userMessages;
    
    /**
     * This method is to check valid login.
     * 
     * @param userName
     *            UserMaster
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public UserMasterVo getLogin(String userName) {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<UserEntity> userList = (List<UserEntity>) getEntityManger()
                .createQuery("SELECT e FROM UserEntity e where e.activeFlag= '1' and  e.userLoginId = :uname").setParameter("uname", userName)
                .getResultList();

        if (userList != null && userList.size() > 0) {
            UserMasterVo userMstr = new UserMasterVo();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(userList.get(0), userMstr);

//          String dycryptedPassword = null;
//          try {
//              dycryptedPassword = CodeSecurity.decrypt(userList.get(0).getPassword());
//          } catch (Exception e) {
//              e.printStackTrace();
//          }
//          userMstr.setPassword(dycryptedPassword.toString());
            userMstr.setPassword(userList.get(0).getPassword());

            if (null != userList.get(0).getUserRoleEntity().getId()
                    && userList.get(0).getUserRoleEntity().getId() != 0) {
                UserRoleMasterVo roleMstr = new UserRoleMasterVo();
                roleMstr.setId(userList.get(0).getUserRoleEntity().getId());
                roleMstr.setRoleType(userList.get(0).getUserRoleEntity().getRoleType());

                if (null != roleMstr.getRoleType()) {
                    UserTypeEntity userTypeEntity = getEntityManger().find(UserTypeEntity.class,
                            roleMstr.getRoleType());
                    userMstr.setUrl(userTypeEntity.getUrl());
                }

                userMstr.setUserRoleMaster(roleMstr);
            }
            if (null != userList.get(0).getUserLocationEntity().getId()
                    && userList.get(0).getUserLocationEntity().getId() != 0) {
                UserLocationMasterVo locationMstr = new UserLocationMasterVo();
                locationMstr.setId(userList.get(0).getUserLocationEntity().getId());
                userMstr.setUserLocationMaster(locationMstr);
            }
            if (null != userList.get(0).getUserDepartmentEntity().getId()
                    && userList.get(0).getUserDepartmentEntity().getId() != 0) {
                UserDepartmentMasterVo departmentMstr = new UserDepartmentMasterVo();
                departmentMstr.setId(userList.get(0).getUserDepartmentEntity().getId());
                userMstr.setUserDepartmentMaster(departmentMstr);
            }
            return userMstr;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

//these are test cases where exactly i am getting null pointer

```
class LoginControllerTestTest {

     @Mock
        private UserLoginService userLoginService;

        @Mock
        private HttpServletRequest request;

        @Mock
        private UserConstants userConstants;

        @InjectMocks
        private LoginController loginController;

        @Before
        public void setup() {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }

        @Test
        public void testPostFormSuccessful() throws Exception {
            // Mocking the request
            when(request.getHeader("authorization")).thenReturn("Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=");

            // Mocking the service response
            UserMasterVo userMasterVo = new UserMasterVo();
            when(userLoginService.getLogin("data.admin2")).thenReturn(userMasterVo);

            // Mocking userConstants
            when(userConstants.getLogFilePath()).thenReturn("/keva/D:/logs");

            // Mocking successful password decryption
            when(CodeSecurity.decrypt(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(true);

            // Mocking TokenManager
            // Add TokenManager related mockings as needed

            // Testing the postForm function
            Response response = loginController.postForm(request, new User());
            assertEquals("200", response.getResponseCode());
            assertEquals("Success", response.getResponseMessage());
            // Add more assertions based on your expected results
        }

        @Test
        public void testPostFormInvalidCredentials() {
            // Mocking the request
            when(request.getHeader("authorization")).thenReturn("InvalidAuthorizationHeader");

            // Testing the postForm function
            Response response = loginController.postForm(request, new User());
            assertEquals("401", response.getResponseCode());
            assertEquals("Invalid user name and password", response.getResponseMessage());
            // Add more assertions based on your expected results
        }

        @Test
        public void testPostFormServiceReturnsNull() {
            // Mocking the request
            when(request.getHeader("authorization")).thenReturn("Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=");

            // Mocking the service response
            when(userLoginService.getLogin("username")).thenReturn(null);

            // Testing the postForm function
            Response response = loginController.postForm(request, new User());
            assertEquals("401", response.getResponseCode());
            assertEquals("Invalid user name and password", response.getResponseMessage());
            
        }

       
    }



// i am trying write junit test cases for loginform /PostForm 




 public Response postForm(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody User user) {
        Response errorResponse = new Response();
        errorResponse.setResponseCode("401");
        errorResponse.setResponseMessage("Invalid user name and password");
        errorResponse.setSuccesObject(null);
        
        try {
            String baseKey = request.getHeader("authorization");
            if (baseKey != null) {
                byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(baseKey.split("\\s+")[1]);
                String decodedString = new String(decodedBytes);
                String credintial[] = decodedString.split(":");
                if (credintial.length == 2) {
                    String userName = credintial[0];
                    String password = credintial[1];
                    
                UserMasterVo mstUserActionVo = userLoginService.getLogin(userName);
                 if (mstUserActionVo != null) {
                    boolean isPasswordmatched = CodeSecurity.decrypt(password,mstUserActionVo.getPassword());
                    // Check the match of the Password.
                        if (isPasswordmatched) {
                            
                          //Log Monitoring
                            File file = new File(userConstants.getLogFilePath());
                            if(file.exists()){
                              FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(userConstants.getLogFilePath()+"/LogMonitor.txt",true); 
                              writer.write(Integer.toString(serialNo++).concat(". "
                               +dateFormat. format(new Date())).concat("("+request.getRemoteAddr()+")  "+userName).concat(System.lineSeparator()));
                              writer.close();
                            }
                            
                            // To Generate the Token
                            String token = baseKey.split("\\s+")[1];// TokenManager.generateToken(baseKey);
                            
                             UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
                             token = uuid.toString();
                             mstUserActionVo.setUserIpAddress(request.getRemoteAddr());
                                
                            AuthUserInfo authUserInfo = new AuthUserInfo(mstUserActionVo);
                            TokenManager.tokenMap.put(token, authUserInfo);

                            if (TokenManager.isTokenAvailable(token)) {
                                TokenManager.setTokenInContext(token);
                            }
                            authUserInfo.getUserMaster().setTokenDate(new Date());
                            TokenManager.tokenMap.put(token, authUserInfo);
                            
                            Token resToken = new Token();
//                          resToken.setAccess_token(baseKey.split("\\s+")[1]);
                            resToken.setAccess_token(token);
                            resToken.setRedirect_path(AuthUtil.getAuthUserInfo().getUserMaster().getUrl());
                            errorResponse.setResponseCode("200");
                            errorResponse.setResponseMessage("Success");
                            errorResponse.setFirstName(AuthUtil.getAuthUserInfo().getUserMaster().getFirstName());
                            errorResponse.setRoleTypeId(mstUserActionVo.getUserRoleMaster().getRoleType());
                            errorResponse.setSuccesObject(resToken);
                            return errorResponse;
                            
                        } else {
                            // Throw the Message If userName or Password are Invalid
                            return errorResponse;
                        }
                    } else {
                        return errorResponse;
                    }
                } else {
                    return errorResponse;
                }
            } else {
                return errorResponse;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            return errorResponse;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you already go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it?